# SQL time difference between two dates multiple conditions

Tags: ms-access, multiple-columns, lag, days

I have a table (T1) which looks like that :

```
    ID  Date    Event
1   01/01/2010  A
1   04/01/2010  B
1   06/01/2010  A
1   09/01/2010  A
1   15/01/2010  B
2   01/02/2010  A
2   04/04/2010  A
2   01/02/2010  C
2   04/04/2010  C
```

I would like to calculate the difference between two dates based on "ID" and "Event" Columns. I would need  a table (T2) which looks like that :

```
ID  Date    Date2   Ndays   Event
1   01/01/2010  06/01/2010  5   A
1   06/01/2010  09/01/2010  3   A
1   04/01/2010  15/01/2010  11  B
2   01/02/2010  04/04/2010  62  A
2   01/02/2010  04/04/2010  62  C
```

Comment: This looks like a gaps and islands style problem, which could be tricky to solve on Access (which does not support analytic functions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple *Group By* query will do:

```sql
SELECT 
    Events.ID, 
    Min(Events.Date) AS Date1, 
    Max(Events.Date) AS Date2, 
    DateDiff('d',[Date1],[date2]) AS NDays, 
    Events.Event
FROM 
    Events
GROUP BY 
    Events.ID, 
    Events.Event;
```

Output:

[image]

**Edit:**

For more records, use a subquery:

```sql
SELECT 
    Events.ID, 
    Events.Date AS Date1, 
    (Select Min(T.Date) 
    From Events As T 
    Where T.ID = Events.ID And T.Event = Events.Event And T.Date > Events.Date) AS Date2, DateDiff('d',[Date1],[date2]) AS NDays, 
    Events.Event
FROM 
    Events
GROUP BY 
    Events.ID, 
    Events.Date, 
    Events.Event
HAVING 
    (Select Min(T.Date) 
    From Events As T 
    Where T.ID = Events.ID And T.Event = Events.Event And T.Date > Events.Date) Is Not Null
ORDER BY 
    Events.ID, 
    Events.Event, 
    Events.Date;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi thank you very much. It works very well.unfortunately I realized that for some ID I can have more than 2 dates for the same event. I've edited my question accordingly (see ID 1 event A); Thanks again

Comment: See extended answer, please.

Answer (score 0):

With a self join and aggregation:

```
SELECT t.ID, t.Date, 
  MIN(tt.Date) AS Date2, 
  DATEDIFF('d', t.Date, Date2) AS NDays,
  t.Event
FROM tablename t INNER JOIN tablename tt
ON tt.ID = t.ID AND tt.Event = t.Event AND t.Date < tt.Date
GROUP BY t.ID, t.Date, t.Event
ORDER BY t.ID, t.Event, t.Date
```

Results:

```
ID  Date        Date2       NDays   Event
1   1/1/2010    6/1/2010    5       A
1   6/1/2010    9/1/2010    3       A
1   4/1/2010    15/1/2010   11      B
2   1/2/2010    4/4/2010    62      A
2   1/2/2010    4/4/2010    62      C
```